# Extract keys from nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, key, reduce

I'm trying to write a one-liner to extract the keys from a 2-level nested dictionary in python.

Here's a sample of my data:

```
values = [(u'Andy', OrderedDict([(u'en', 102)])), (u'Ben', OrderedDict([(u'es', 1)])), (u'Jane', OrderedDict([(u'EN', 719), (u'en', 969)])), (u'Steve', OrderedDict([(u'fr', 1)])), (u'Susanne', OrderedDict([(u'nl', 2)]))]
```

The expected result would be:

```
[u'en', u'es', u'EN', u'fr', u'nl']
```

So far I've tried:

```
map(lambda x: x[1].keys(), values.items())
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'

reduce(lambda k, v: v.keys(), values.items())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

This needs to be a one-liner as I am inserting the code in a Jinja template, hence I'm trying to use lambda. I'm quite new to Python though, perhaps I am misunderstanding something...?

Comment: does the result need to preserve order?

Comment: Hi @timgeb no need to preserve the order.

Answer (score 1):

`values` is not a dictionary, it is a list which has no `items` attribute. Here's one solution with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> list(set(chain.from_iterable(x[1].keys() for x in values)))
[u'fr', u'en', u'nl', u'es', u'EN']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
In [10]: reduce(lambda x,y:x+y ,map(lambda x:x[1].keys(), values))
Out[10]: [u'en', u'es', u'EN', u'en', u'fr', u'nl']
```

The `map` is getting all the keys from the dict.
The reduce does the job of combining the result of nested lists.
If you need unique values(destroys order), use `set`-

```
In [11]: list(set(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y ,map(lambda x:x[1].keys(), values))))
Out[11]: [u'fr', u'en', u'nl', u'es', u'EN']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
list(set([y for x in values for y in x[1].keys()]))
```